# Map the position of one bell curve on another

Tags: algebra-precalculus

***My Problem:***

I have some data that will roughly follow the shape of a bell curve. My data could contain only the start of the curve, only the end of the curve, or the entire of the curve. What I want to do is compare my data with a standard predefined bell curve in order to figure of what part of the bell curve my data represents.

***An example to put things in context:***

Lets say I have 10,000 widgets (a car part perhaps) and what I am modeling is how long it takes a widget to fail. With time in years on the x axis and number of failures per year on the y axis. You would initially expect to see few failures as the widgets are brand new, then you would see the rate of failures increase over time as the majority of widgets ware out, and then you would expect to see failures tail off as the few working widgets that are left slowly fail.

Now lets say I'm testing a new type of widget and I have data representing the first x number of failures, what I want is to identify mathematically how far along my standard bell curve I am, have the majority of my failures already occured? am I 20% of the way through the cycle? 30%? 70%?

I think that the solution has something to do with gradients however on a bell curve the gradients could be the same at more than one point so it would also involve the rate/direction of change. Any help or equations that could be used to figure this out would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't really have an answer, but I do have a couple of ideas to float.

Essentially what you're trying to do here is to fit the data to a bell curve. In other words, given that the data are approximately normally distributed, we would like to discover what the values of the parameters $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are.

I would try to develop a least squares method of fitting the data to a normal curve (instead of a polynomial). To get my guess close, I may try a regression on Taylor polynomials of varying degrees to see if I can identify how the optimal solution varies as the degree of the polynomials increase. I realize that the final solution will depend on numerical methods.

Something else that may be worth considering may be to graph level curves with $\sigma$ on the x-axis and $\mu$ on the y-axis, with each point on each curve representing equal sum of errors (or squares of errors, or whatever). Analyse these level curves to see if they are convex, and if not, at least to see if their shapes at least predictable? Does that predictability lead us to an optimal solution?

Hopefully some of these ideas have been useful.